# Error : Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Map android.content.SharedPreferences.getAll()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-logcat

Been stuck on this for ages and have tried multiple permutations of things I think could fix it but I'm pretty new to Java and cant figure it out.

So I declare this stuff:

```
public SharedPreferences prefs;
public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

Then in a method later:

```
public void SaveInsult(View view) {
        String saved = insult.getText().toString();
        int number = prefs.getAll().size();
        int newKey = number + 1;
        String newKeyString = "" + newKey;
        editor.putString(newKeyString, saved);
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.addedFavs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

My app will start fine, how ever when I run this code on a button click button click I get error:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Map android.content.SharedPreferences.getAll()' on a null object reference
```

I know I'm missing something I just cant work out where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't initializing prefs:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Your_Key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

Make sure you call this before `editor.putString(newKeyString, saved);`

Comment: I've tried adding this stuff I just cant figure out where I should be putting it  should I put it in my method, outside it on in oncreate or where? Thanks

Comment: If the `prefs` object is on an Activity, then putting in `onCreate` sounds reasonable.

Comment: I had to get rid of the first bit of code I posted then I put what you suggested in the method, that's the only way I could get it to work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: nw, make sure to accept the answer if it worked for you.